# nested jquery deferred calls -- not sure how to code final REST / AJAX calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, sharepoint, jquery-deferred

I have a SharePoint form which I have added in an editable table that allows the user to add, edit and delete items from a child list that have a many to one relationship with the parent item on the form.

To manage this I override the submit functionality and run the below code that uses AJAX and the SharePoint Rest api to handle inserts and updates on the child list before submitting the form.

Partial cod of submit override:

```
$.when(bulkInsert(arrayOfNew, parentId)
).then(function() { 
    $.when(bulkUpdate(arrayOfUpdates,parentId)
    ).then(function() {
        alert("all done");
        //run initial submit
    });
});
```

Both bulkInsert and bulkUpdate work the same and the problem is with the final nested Rest/AJAX calls so will only show the updateItems.

```
function bulkUpdate(updates, parentId) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    var promises= [];
    $.map(updates, function (item) {
        promises.push(updateItem(parentId, item))
    })

    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function () { deferred.resolve(); });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

I believe my code to this point is correct.

To update the item using the SharePoint Rest api I must first get the RequestDigest and REST URI for the item, so the final ajax call is nested in the success branch of the function for the select AJAX call to get the item. I've tried several things and none have worked so I will just show the working code, and hopefully someone can show me how to add the needed deferred code to make the script work correctly.

```
function updateItem(parentId, childItem) {
    getItem(childItem.Id, function (data) {
        //complete function
        var updateItem = {
            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.ChildListItem" },
            "LookupID": parentId,
            "Field1": item.Field1,
            "Field2": item.Field2,
            "Field3": item.Field3 //etc.
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: data.d.results[0].__metadata.uri,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(updateItem),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": data.d.results[0].__metadata.etag
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("update succesful");
                //
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        });
    }, function (data) {
       //failure function
       alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
 }

function getItem(childId, complete, failure) {
    $.ajax({
        url: (_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl == "/" ? "" : _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl) + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ChildList')/items?select=ID&$filter=ID eq " + childId,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            // Returning the results
            alert("got item");
            complete(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the main routine should simplify as follows :

```
bulkInsert(arrayOfNew, parentId).then(function() {
    bulkUpdate(arrayOfUpdates, parentId).then(function() {
        alert("all done");
        //run initial submit
    });
});
```

*I'm not sure about `arrayOfUpdates` Where does it come from? Is it generated by `bulkInsert`?*

Then, `bulkUpdate` can be simplified as follows :

```
function bulkUpdate(updates, parentId) {
    var promises = $.map(updates, function(item) {
        return updateItem(parentId, item);
    });
    return $.when.apply($, promises);
}
```

Then, `updateItem` must return a promise, and would probably benefit from internal refactoring as follows :

```
function updateItem(parentId, childItem) {
    function getItem(id) {
        //Note the `return`
        return $.ajax({
            url: (_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl == "/" ? "" : _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl) + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ChildList')/items?select=ID&$filter=ID eq " + id,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        });
    }
    function update(data) {
        var requestData = {
            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.ChildListItem" },
            "LookupID": parentId,
            "Field1": item.Field1,
            "Field2": item.Field2,
            "Field3": item.Field3 //etc.
        };
        //Note the `return`
        return $.ajax({
            url: data.d.results[0].__metadata.uri,
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": data.d.results[0].__metadata.etag
            }
        });
    }

    //Closure-forming utility for success/error reporting
    function reportAjaxStatus(prefix) {
        return function (x, textStatus) {
           var message = (prefix || '-') + (textStatus || '-');
           alert(message);
        }
    }

    //Master routine (simplify when debugged)
    //Note the `return`
    return getItem(childItem.Id)
        .always(reportAjaxStatus('getItem: '))
        .then(update)
        .always(reportAjaxStatus('update: '));
}
```

This makes for a concise, readable master routine, which is in control of all success/error reporting, and easily simplified when everything is debugged.

Comment: This solution resolved my problem and was very helpful in structuring my code. I have several other nested deferred calls that although working can be simplified with the above. -thanks.

Comment: Aye, returning promises is key. Everything else is a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

`updateItem()` doesn't return a promise.

```
function updateItem(parentId, childItem) {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    getItem(childItem.Id, function (data) {

        $.ajax({
            success: function (data) {
                def.resolve(true);
            },
        });

    });

    return def.promise();
 }
```

Comment: This solution easily resolved the problem with the similar InsertItem call because there was no additional call to first get the item being updated. -Thanks.